# How to use createPattern from Context2D QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I want to use
`variant createPattern(Image image, string repetition)`, but I don't know how to pass the image parameter. I tried to pass the id of an Image but the function returns an empty object.

`variant createPattern(color color, enumeration patternMode)` works like a charm.

Comment: It looks that `createPattern` works only with string url, like `var ptrn = ctx.createPattern("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/222/Canvas_createpattern.png", "repeat");` all other options (Image,  CanvasImageData etc.) do nothing. Looks like a bug.

Comment: I've created issue in bug tracker - [https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57512](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57512)

Answer (score 1):

As @folibis said, the source of 
  *createPattern* should be an url.
For anyone looking for an example, here it is:

```
Canvas {
    id:canvas
    anchors.fill: parent
    onPaint:{
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var pattern = ctx.createPattern("file:///path_to_my_image.ext", 'repeat');
        ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
  Component.onCompleted: canvas.requestPaint();
}
```